# Hibernate validator how to validate the object including its related objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have a Event class, with many to one Person objects associated with it,  (which in turn has its own validator annoations on it. When I validate my Event class though, it's not calling the validation on the related object?

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Event>> cv = getValidator().validate(i);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotate the `Person` field in `Event` with `@Valid` to have the validation also validate the `Person` instance.